# How to wire many bi-color LEDs to a single power supply, and switch them on/off individually

Tags: power-supply, led, relay, dc

My goal is to have 13 separate stations, each with a bi-color, common cathode LED ([Dialight 606](http://www.dialight.com/Assets/Brochures_And_Catalogs/Indication/MDEL606X001.pdf)). These LEDs do not require external current limiting resistors. Each LED can be 'On Green', 'On Red', or Off.

I have a 1 AMP, 12VDC power supply and four '8 Channel' relays. I am able to discretely control each channel of the each '8 Channel' relay via a 3rd party control system. I am not sure how to correctly wire the LEDs, relays and power supply in order to accomplish this. Please let me know if any additional info is required to help figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

Power supply V+ to relay, relay to led anode, led cathode to power supply ground. Nothing special. Keep in mind your power supply, if it powers the Relay control side of the relay modules, should be the right current capacity.  1 Amp may be too low

Comment: The relays are powered separately (the 12V supply I mentioned is only for the LEDs). So would [this](http://i.imgur.com/UAsm4fp.gif) work?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the layout needed